# Check exact digit in number in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

When I insert a number into a table, I need to check, if some digits of this number fulfill few constraints. Is there a way I can accomplish this?
In Python, for example, I could use index `number[n]` or `regex`. I thought of using `LIKE`, but i had read that `LIKE` is only used in `WHERE` clause so it won't work.

Simple code:

```
CREATE TABLE Person(  
    id INT NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR(40)  
)    

-- this constraint is just how I would imagine it 
ALTER TABLE Person ADD CONSTRAINT Check_id CHECK (id[2] <> 0 AND id[3] <> 0);  

INSERT INTO Person(1234, 'John'); -- not error
INSERT INTO Person(1204, 'Mike'); -- error
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Show the table structure, show sample data, show the code you wrote that doesn't produce what you want, and show what you want the expected output to look like.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle? (LIKE can be used in check constraints.)

Comment: I am using Oracle.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do. The integer literal 042 turns into 42 before the check constraint is evaluated.

Comment: That was just an example. I need to check few constraints, like if 4th and 5th digits are not 0 etc.

Comment: I changed a code, hope my question is a bit clearer now.

Comment: Whatever you read about the `LIKE` operator is incorrect. `LIKE` can be used anywhere a logical condition can be used: `WHERE` clause, `HAVING` clause (after a `GROUP BY`), join conditions, `DEFINE` clause in a `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`, etc. This includes constraints. However, it doesn't seem to be the best choice for your problem. But do keep that in mind about `LIKE` in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can base your check on a Regular Expression, e.g. to check that the last two digits are not zero:

```
check (regexp_like(to_char(id), '[^0][^0]$'))
```

`[^0]` = not a zero

`$` = end of string

Or to check that the 2nd and 3rd digit is not a zero:

```
check (regexp_like(to_char(id), '^.[^0][^0]))
```

`.`= any character

`^` = begin of string/number

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
ALTER TABLE Person ADD CONSTRAINT chk_person_id
    CHECK (id not like '_0%' and id not like '__0%');
```

Oracle will convert the `id` to a string for the `like`.  I'm not really thrilled with representing the `id` as a number.  Personally, I think it would be better to represent it as a string.

Comment: I agree completely, if there are conditions on the second or third digit not to be 0, it is almost certain the ID values are not meant as numbers, but as strings made up entirely of digits. Thumbs up also for using standard string comparison vs. the "lazy option" (regular expressions).

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it is best to use standard string functions and operators (`INSTR`, `SUBSTR`, `LIKE` etc.) over regular expression solutions, which are much more time- and resource-consuming. Use regular expressions only for complicated problems, where the standard functions either simply don't work or give a solution that is difficult to write and to maintain.

In this case, a simple solution is

```
ALTER TABLE Person 
      ADD CONSTRAINT Check_id CHECK ( 0 NOT IN (SUBSTR(id, 2, 1), SUBSTR(id, 3, 1)) );
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am new to SQL, so it is  my fault I didn't describe my problem properly. I think in my situation, regex is more usable. Thank you for advice !